# Prevent jQuery dialog focusing opener on close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How would I prevent a jQuery dialog focusing its opener on close?

I have a big textarea that is focused when a dialog is opened. If the page is scrolled down to the bottom, when the dialog is open. When the dialog is closed jQuery UI focuses the textarea, and make the page jump back up to the top.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/bPqF2/1/

Click the anchor, then close the dialog.

```
<div>
    <a id="click-me" href="#bottom">Click me</a>
</div>
<div>
    <textarea style="height: 2000px">
        ...
    </textarea>
</div>
<div>
    <a id="bottom" name="bottom"></a>
</div>

$(function() {
    $('#click-me').click(function() {
        $('textarea').focus();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('<div>').text('Close me please!').dialog({
                modal: true
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The offending line of jQuery UI is https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/86eaa30994657b650b26388e87ecff679cf93a50/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js#L181

*(note: the above is only an automated example, in the real use case the user scroll the window down, a dialog is opened (by clicking a button that doesn't steal focus, using `user-select: none`), and when it is closed the window jumps back to the top).*

*If you see this: http://jsfiddle.net/bPqF2/9 and click the text area, scroll down, and wait for the dialog to popup, when its closed the windows is scrolled to the top.*

Comment: Why do you have a focus() there?

Comment: @FrancisKim as an automated example. In my real use case the textarea has been manually focused by the user when the dialog is opened.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?  You can adjust the scroll to your liking.  You could also scroll to the end of the text area if you like

```
<div> 
    <a id="click-me" href="#bottom">Click me</a>
</div>
<div>
    <textarea id="myTxtArea" style="height: 2000px"></textarea>
</div>
<div> 
     <a id="bottom" name="bottom"></a>
</div>
<div data-role="dialog" id="myDialog"></div>

$(function () {
    $('#click-me').click(function () {
        var pos = $(document).scrollTop(); // get current position before focus
        $('textarea').focus();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#myDialog').text('Close me please!').dialog({
                modal: true,
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    console.log("dialog has closed");
                    $('#myTxtArea').blur();
                    $("html, body").scrollTop(pos);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

[Here is a demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rossmartin/WJGut/)

Comment: I don't want it to scroll to the end. I want it not to scroll at all. (retain the scroll position that when the dialog was opened).

Comment: Ok, I think just the `blur` on the textarea should accomplish that?

Comment: No, as per the original it is scrolled to the top on close.

Comment: @Petah I made a new edit, this should work for you now I hope.  If you trigger a click to bring up that dialog via console you can see that when the dialog gets closed you will be brought back to the original scroll height.

Comment: Well, yea that is a possible workaround. But I would rather prevent it happening altogether. The offending code is: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js#L181

Comment: This method was the only one that worked consistently for me. Note that the jQuery-UI dialog accepts an `open` handler (much like the `close` handler in Ross's answer). So if you can add `open: function() { pos = $(document).scrollTop(); }` to the dialog instead of relying on the `click` handler.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `href="#bottom"` to `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Why don't you add a `.blur()` to undo the user's focus on the textarea?

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bPqF2/8/

Comment: Like I said in my comment, that was just an automated example. If you see this: http://jsfiddle.net/bPqF2/9/ and click the text area, scroll down, and wait for the dialog to popup, when its closed the windows is scrolled to the top.

Comment: @Petah I understand that it's automated. But if it's manually focused then you should make it blur anyway to prevent default browser actions (scroll up)?

Comment: Also it scrolls down initially since you have linked to the anchor. It's not jQuery.dialog() doing it.

Comment: Did you look at the second example? Even if you scroll down manually it does it. And yes it is jQuery UI doing it. It is infact this exact line: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js#L181

Comment: @Petah I don't see how that code is making your window scroll up.

Comment: Your idea to blur the textarea when the dialog is opened may work. I will confirm and come back. The code in jQuery UI focuses the opener, which in this case is off the top of the screen, hence making it scroll up.

Comment: @Petah no, the jQuery UI code blurs the active element, shifting the focus back to what it was previously (textarea) and your browser moves the window up.

Comment: You mean this code: `this.opener.filter(":focusable").focus()`?

Comment: @Petah `$( this.document[0].activeElement ).blur();`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33525/discussion-between-francis-kim-and-petah)